# spring security showing 403 error while logging in using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-security, http-status-code-403

I know there are many questions already available, related to this error but I have tried almost everything, nothing fixed my issue.

when I sumbmitting my form in browser console, I am seeing

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

My project is in Spring 4.0.3, spring security 4.0.1, java 8 and running on wildfly 8.x server

my ajax call is

```
 $.ajax({
           url: "j_spring_security_check",    
           data: $('#loginForm').serialize(), 
           type: "POST",
           beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Ajax-call", "true");
           },
           success: function(result) {       
                if (result == "not-ok") {
                  $('.error').show();
                  $('.login-error').html(CREDENTIAL_CHECK) ;
                  return false;
                } else {
                    $('.error').hide();
                    document.location = result;
                }
           },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $('.error').show();
                $('.login-error').html(NETWORK_CHECK) ;
                return false; 
            }
        });
```

my security configuration:

```
<security:form-login    login-page="/home" 
                        default-target-url="/home"
                        authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthenticationFailureHandler" 
                        authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
/>
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" 
                 invalidate-session="true" 
                 delete-cookies="SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE" 
/>
```

I tried to set

```
<security:headers disabled="true" />

<security:csrf disabled="true" />
```

It is not working.in Server console also, I am not seeing any error.

What else can I do to fix this error? already I have wasted 2 days in this issue

Comment: Url is `login` not `j_spring_security_check`.

Comment: How are you saying this?

Comment: check your ajax url in controller is existing or not. and make sure that your RequestMethod.POST in your controller.

Comment: The login url changed in spring security 4 to match the one used in java config.

Comment: for that also it is showing 403 error..I think..problem is something else..I am using wildfly8

Comment: Are you submitting to the correct URL? Currently it looks like a relative instead of an absolute one. Please add your full configuration and check the logs on what is happening

Comment: in console, it is saying `http://localhost/app/j_spring_security_check 403(forbidden)`...means it is submitting to correct URL but anyhow my server or application is not allowing this submission.

Answer (score 1):

that problem create CSFR Protection because in Spring Security 4.x is enabled default and all GET and POST request have token, when you dont create this token server show you 403 error. You can easily disable this security
here you have xml conf http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html
and java conf http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html